# Header and Footer Overlays Content - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using [Bootstrap Cover Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/) to make a clean website with few content: basically some text and an image.

Header and footer overlaying the website content as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: twitter bootstrap]

Website: [merdanacabeca.com/adrenalina/](http://merdanacabeca.com/adrenalina/)

What is the best solution in this case?
Media-query?

I know that I can add top-margin to the content `<div>` and change footer's position to static instead of fixed. However, this leads to other problems in different screen resolutions (smaller for example).

I'm looking for the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem derives from the fixed position of .masthead & .mastfoot classes.

Try removing the fixed position of .mastfoot and the following for .masthead and .cover :

```
.masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #333333;
} 

.cover {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-top: 115px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i've understood your question correctly, you're trying to stop the footer with text "Desenvolvido por ..." from overlaying that white button (correct me if not).

well it's because of the `padding-bottom` of the `.inner` class that the text stands there. you can reduce that...

also i don't think that you need `position: fixed` for footer. cause usually it stay at the bottom of the page.

you can also assign `margin-top` to the `<div class="inner cover">` to make the problem with the header go away

Comment: i think it would work on smaller screen too. because in an small or big screens it's always OK to use scroll-Y. and assigning a `margin-top` in pixels to your content would always keep the header from overlaying content. and if the height of your header changes in different screens, you can use this: `@media (min-width: ...px) {
    .content
    {
        margin-top: ...px;
    }
}` and write it for all different stages of screen width.

Comment: and about footer, i think if you simply put it at the bottom of your page, -like many many other websites- you can handle it in different sizes like a regular element, and it will always stay at the bottom of your page...

Comment: GHB, I'm not much familiar with media-queries, especially which ranges I have to cover. About footer, I can change it's "position". I didn't change before because I was using the [default example from Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/). Finally, the problem of using "margin-top" - without media-queries, is that in lower screens the content will be pulled down more than needed.

Comment: well i think the basic variations of screen widths would be `600 px`, `960px`, `1280px` and `1920px`. but your html might be changing on different widths(depending on how you've wrote it). so basically you should see at what pixels your header's height changes, and for each of them, use `@media...` in your css file and assign the correct amount of `margin-top` to the main container...

Comment: I guess I'll end up by re-positioning both, header and footer, staticly instead of "fixed".